# React Native uploading file to multer, i am getting empty buffer

Tags: react-native, axios, multer

I am making an App with React Native and back end with NodeJS. From VueJS it is exactly the same code(except i am getting the file from an input), and its working fine from an Input and Postman, but i am having trouble on React Native

Code in the App:

```
const formdata = new FormData()
const file = myMainImage
console.log(file)
const fileName = file.split("/").reverse()[0];
formdata.append('media', {
  url: file,
  name: fileName,
  type: 'image/jpeg'
})
await profileApi.uploadMyMainImage(formdata)
```

And the request to the backend (tried with axios and fetch)

```
const postFormMethodWithAuthorization = async (url, content) => {
  const headers = getHeaderWithAuthorizationForm()
  const response = await Axios.post(url, content, {headers} )
  return response.data
}

const postFileusingFetch = async  (url, content) => {
  const result = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Header(await getHeaderWithAuthorizationForm()),
    body: content
  })
  return await result.json()
}
```

but in the back end i am always getting from req.file:

```
 

 {
  fieldname: 'media',
  originalname: 'DADE2091-0C50-456B-8F89-408CCAD98E02.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  buffer: <Buffer >,
  size: 0
}
```

Any Ideas? i thought it can be something related to the file being upload, so i treated it like a stream, but same problem happens, also i am uploading it into AWS S3, but when i get it back the file is empty and cant be opened.
The image uri is being taken from the Camera. I also tried removing file:// with no luck.

Any Help appreciated!

Comment: If anybody seees this, i couldnt find a solution, so i decided to encode it to base 64, and send as JSON. It works.

Comment: I had the same problem, after lot of research I discovered I was using `source`, in your case the problem is that you are using `url` instead of `uri` as key in the `formdata.append(... )`

Comment: Having the same problem!! When you say you send it as a json do you mean you are no longer using a multipart form?